# Git parent branch is getting changes of child branch

Tags: git

I have a branch called `branch1`.

I create a child branch by doing

```
git checkout -b branch2
```

Then I checkout to `branch2` by doing

```
git checkout branch2
```

I make some changes on `branch2`

When I checkout to `branch1`, I see my code changes I made in `branch2`.

I don't want parent branch to sync with child branch. I will merge the code changes of child branch into parent branch when I feel that child branch has correct code.

How can I avoid parent branch from getting code changes of child branch ?

Comment: Just to be sure, you're committing the changes on your child branch before you switch, right? If you don't make a commit, the changes will remain as part of the working copy, waiting to be committed to a specific branch.

Comment: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1

Comment: @sager have you figured out the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the way git works. Before switching back to branch1, you either have to `commit` the changes you made in branch2 or `stash` them for later.